# How do I mirror my hard drive?

Tags: applications, hard-drive

How do I mirror my hard drive?  I want to preserve programs for which I've lost the license number.

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by 'mirror'? Are you running any sort of backup scheme on your computer, such as Apple's Time Machine, CarbonCopyCloner or SuperDuper!® ?

Comment: I'm using Time Machine, but I understand it won't copy either Office 2011 or Adobe Design and Web Premium CS6 when I want to restore my disc after partitioning it (so I can use Naturally Speaking for Windows on my Mac).  Would CarbonCopyCloner or SuperDuper do the job?  Which is preferable?

Comment: If you're partitioning to add a bootcamp partition & already have sufficient space to do that, then [theoretically] there would be no data loss. Backup always recommended, of course. CCC or SD could do that.

Comment: I've restored my own iMac from a Time Machine backup, including Office 2011 and Adobe CS5 without having to reload license codes. I've _not_ partitioned my drive to install Windows just to run one app, however. Have you taken a look at the OS X [Dragon Dictate](http://www.nuance.com/for-individuals/by-product/dragon-for-mac/index.htm) to avoid the Windows (Bootcamp?) install?

Comment: Editing Dragon Dictate is a nightmare, and if you have other things to do with your life, you should avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking to "mirror" a hard drive often means setting up a RAID where one drive mirrors the other. This is done using either the RAID software built into Disk Utility or 3rd party RAID software.

The benefits of that is that each drive is a duplicate of the other and if one fails the other disk has all your valuable data. The "problem" is that you generally cant set up RAID across a USB or Thunderbolt bus (that I am aware of). So if you have a Mac with one internal drive you can't set up a RAID between the internal and an external drive.

You can also use a utility like SuperDuper, Carbon Copy Cloner (and others) to make a bootable duplicate of your HD, essentially making a mirror copy of the drive, just not done in real time like a RAID mirror would.

Both of those applications can be scheduled to run on a regular basis (hourly, daily, weekly, etc.) and copy only the changed files to the backup drive.

I use SuperDuper to do just this and it is scheduled to run every other day automatically. It connects to another Mac that is always on, mounts a disk image and backs up the changed files.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want to do is to create a bootable backup of your hard drive.  There are several good utilities for this (ChronoSync is my favorite).  The benefit of a bootable backup is that not only can you restore files from it, but you can also directly boot from it if the hard drive in your computer should ever fail.